# add an ad banner in uiViewController in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, banner, admob

I want to add and ad banner, I used google framework

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
```

in my pod file

I added a view to my uiViewController > GoogleBannerView

this is my code

import GoogleMobileAds

in the viewdidLoad:

```
    GoogleBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-5462393278951241/1172515484"
    GoogleBannerView.delegate = self
    GoogleBannerView.rootViewController = self
    GoogleBannerView.load(GADRequest())
```

But it doesn't display anything in the view and gives me a message in the console:

To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks..

Comment: Check in iPhone once , not in simulator @ema so

Answer (score 2):

I display a footer (320x50) ad that will come up from the bottom if there is one and ease out if there stops being one to serve. This is a heavy implementation and could be simplified if you didn't want to hide/show the space.

My UIViewController has a hard coded view with constraints (320 width, 50 height, centered Horizontal, pinned to bottom of safe area. I link the following:

- Ad View to bannerView
- Ad View height constraint to bannerViewHeightConstraint

> Note that in the code sample I use your adUnitID. Our ID looks different as we are using DFP.

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class SomeClass: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: DFPBannerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bannerView.delegate = self
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-5462393278951241/1172515484"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.validAdSizes = [ NSValueFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner) ]
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        bannerView.frame.origin.y += bannerView.frame.size.height
        bannerView.isHidden = true

        let request = GADRequest()
    //***** NOTE : per Google Documentation (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/test-ads)
    //        "iOS simulators are automatically configured as test devices."
//      request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ] //***** This was requried in previous versions, now on automatically done, don't think you can disable it.
        bannerView.load(request)
    }
}

extension SomeClass : GADBannerViewDelegate
{
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("*** adViewDidReceiveAd for 'Banner' at \(Date())")
        if bannerView == self.bannerView
        {
            if bannerView.isHidden
            {
                bannerView.frame.origin.y += bannerView.frame.size.height
                bannerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
                bannerView.isHidden = false

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                    bannerView.frame.origin.y -= bannerView.frame.size.height
                    self.bannerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 50
                }, completion: nil )
            }
        }
    }

    /// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("*** adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription) for 'Banner'")
        if bannerView == self.bannerView
        {
            print("Hidden: \(bannerView.isHidden)")
            if !bannerView.isHidden
            {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                    bannerView.frame.origin.y += bannerView.frame.size.height
                    self.bannerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
                }, completion: {finished in
                    if finished
                    {
                        bannerView.isHidden = true
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that a full screen view will be presented in response
    /// to the user clicking on an ad.
    func adViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("*** adViewWillPresentScreen for 'Banner'")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the full screen view will be dismissed.
    func adViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("*** adViewWillDismissScreen for 'Banner'")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the full screen view has been dismissed.
    func adViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("*** adViewDidDismissScreen for 'Banner'")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
    /// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
    func adViewWillLeaveApplication(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("*** adViewWillLeaveApplication for 'Banner'")
    }
}
```